# Hiibernate : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to write a simple code for hibernate. I am using SQL Server 2012 as a database. I am encountering the following error while running the application:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:282)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3587)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at com.samples.test.HibernateUtil.main(HibernateUtil.java:28)
```

Sep 05, 2015 7:40:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

This is my Employee entity class

```
 package com.samples.hibernate;

public class Employee {

    private int ID;
    private String name;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is my code where I am communicating with the database.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        session = factory.openSession();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setID(3);
        employee.setName("Venkatesh");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(employee);
        session.getTransaction().commit();


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Class Employee has ID as integer and name as String. Please help me with this. I am new to hibernate and trying to learn. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you post your `Employee` entity class?

Comment: @dazito I have now included my Employee class. Thank You

Comment: Because you used XML configurations, can you add that too? My guess is that your DB originally had String values into the variable name. Try adding the hbm2ddl property of "Create" -> "<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>" and refresh your table to see whether the problem persists.

Comment: The table was created using hbm2ddl update property

Answer (score 1):

It is solved. I recreated .hbm.xml file. Maybe it was taking int as datatype for name.